# Same editable region/content same on all pages

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm working on this [website](http://woodstown-pilesgrove.com/) in WordPress and I want the content with the title "Featured Business" that's on the sidebar to appear on all pages. I created a template for it but it doesn't display when called. The code is as shown below.

```
    <div id="ftb">
      The content
    </div>
    <!-- End FTP -->
```

and I called it with `<?php get_ftb(); ?>` But it doesn't show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display a chunk of html that's part of the sidebar (but not the entire sidebar), I recommend to place it on functions.php, like this:

```
<?php
function get_ftb() {
?>
    <div id="ftb">
      The content
    </div>
    <!-- End FTP -->
<?php } ?>
```

After that you'll be free to call it with get_ftb();

If you just need to call the entire sidebar, use get_sidebar() instead.